# Data model for unlockable card collection

Tags: objective-c, data-structure, xml

My game has a collection of cards (about 64) that are unlocked (one by one) provided that 4 items are collected/gained in the game.

Right now the deck of cards is modeled with a plist file, like this:

```
<plist>
     <dict>
    <key>card1</key>
  <dict>
    <key>available</key>
    <true/>
    <key>series</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>model</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>color</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
</dict>
<key>card2</key>
<dict>
    <key>available</key>
    <false/>
    <key>series</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>model</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>color</key>
    <integer>2</integer>
</dict>
```

The value for the key named "available" marks if the item is locked or not. Right now I have to include the data for the items collected by the user, but including that inside the plist looks like too much hassle.

What kind of structure should be more suitable for this? How do you manage a collection of unlockable items like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume there's gonna be some kind of "save game" mechanic in your game. In this case, the simplest solution is to include in the player's saved game file a list of the cards the player already unlocked.
Unfortunately I'm not familiar with the plist data structure, so I'll just provide an example in xml:

```
<UnlockedCards> 
   <CardId>1</CardId>
   <CardId>5</CardId>
   <CardId>9</CardId>
   <CardId>23</CardId>
</UnlockedCards>
```

The reason I'm using CardId's instead of CardName's, is that your card names might change with localization, or patches (typo fixes etc.). If you associate an Id with each card, then you won't have to worry about those changes.